# Search app store for similar games on pc

Tags: competition, appstore

I want to search the app store for similar games so I can see how much competition there will be for any apps I am thinking of designing.

Knowing how many clones/similar games there are plus there prices and success rate would go a long way in deciding which ideas to take forward.

Is there anyway to do this easily on a pc (I do not have an iPhone)

Answer (score 1):

You can run iTunes and thus browse the store on either Windows or Mac. And actually I think you can browse the store through the iTunes website (not 100% sure of that since I've never tried).

To actually play the games you need an iOS device (iPhone, iPod Touch, or iPad).

Comment: You _can_ browse the app store from the iTunes site, but it's [not nearly the same](http://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios/id36?mt=8) as in iTunes. Might as well just get iTunes.